# How to write the Python equivalent to this MatLab For Loop

Tags: python, matlab, for-loop

I have experience in MatLab and I'm currently transitioning to *Python*. Following is a structure of a `For loop` that I wrote in *MatLab* and I don't understand how to write it in Python.

(btw, the values included here are not important and mostly dummy/rhetoric, I'm more interested in the approach)

```
U = 11;
dt = 0.1;
N = 100;
L = 120;

t(1)=0;
v(1)=0; v_(1)=0;
r(1)=0; r_(1)=0;
    
for i=2:N

    t(i)=dt*(i-1);
    v_(i-1)=v(i-1)/U; 
    r_(i-1)=r(i-1)/(U/L);
end
```

Basically, I want to perform a mathematical computation within a for loop and obtain each value, in order to make an X, Y plot. How can I approach this?

Thanks in Advance!

Edit: This is what I have so far.

```
U = 11
dt = 0.1
N = 100
L = 120

t = []
v_ = []
r_ = []
v = []
r = []

for i in range(N):
    t[i] = dt * (i - 1)
    v_[i - 1] = v[i - 1] / U
    r_[i - 1] = r[i - 1] / (U / L)

    t.append()
    v_.append()
    r_.append()

print(t)
print(v_)
print(r_)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. And yes! I've also looked for similar questions. I understand how to formulate the for loop and append the values to a list. But I don't know how to deal with the ith (i and (i-1)) term on both sides.

Comment: I suggest you just try printing your `i` variable in both Matlab and Python...

Comment: How is your current Python code wrong? Can you explain what the Matlab code does and which part of it you are having trouble formulating in Python?

Comment: The given MATLAB code throws errors, since you're not proplery updating your variables (given `v`, `r`, etc. are not initialized; as assumed from the given code). Apart from that, I highly suggest to have a look at the [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) library. There's a dedicated [NumPy for MATLAB users tutorial](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html).

Comment: @tripleee My Python code is wrong because I **think** the `i in range(N)` starts with 0 (it starts with 1 in MatLab). I think that's what @Matteo V intended with the comment as well.

Comment: Please [edit] to include all this information in the question itself. Python's `range` lets you specify the starting point with `range(1, n+1)`. What it does is easy to find out in the Python REPL (though you have to specify `list(range(1, n+1))` to see what it actually evaluates to).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```py
U = 11
dt = 0.1
N = 10
L = 120

t = [0 for _ in range(N)]
v_ = [0 for _ in range(N)]
r_ = [0 for _ in range(N)]
v = [0 for _ in range(N)]
r = [0 for _ in range(N)]

for i in range(1, N+1): # = matlab i=2:N
    if i < N:
        t[i] = dt * (i - 1)
    v_[i - 1] = v[i - 1] / U
    r_[i - 1] = r[i - 1] / (U / L)

print(t)
print(v_)
print(r_)
```

Can you post some expected output? Currently the result doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Thank you! This will be enough for me to follow and learn the approach. I understand the fault now :)

I'm sorry that my question and the provided code doesn't make much sense. I only wanted to know any approach, so I can try learning the rest myself.

Again, thank you for this!

Comment: currently it will break without the if statement.